# John 1:4 to 1:9 - is it the Light or the light?

Tags: john, christology

Looking at various translations of John 1:4-9, there are a range of uses of capitalization for 'light'.

The [ESV](https://biblehub.com/esv/john/1.htm) keeps everything as 'light'.

The [Berean Study Bible](https://biblehub.com/bsb/john/1.htm) uses 'light' at 1:4 but then switches to 'Light' at 1:5.

The [KJB](https://biblehub.com/kjv/john/1.htm) uses 'light' from 1:4-1:6, and then from 1:7 on uses 'Light'.

What is going on here? Why do some translations capitalize at different points, and some none at all?

Comment: The KJV 1611 and ASV don't have it. It is a fringe practice of translators to capitalize all titles, pronouns for God. It's just due to their insecurity that they keep twisting grammar for their agenda. https://www.billmounce.com/monday-with-mounce/should-we-capitalize-divine-pronouns and see biblehub parallel

Answer (score 3):

Before answering, let me agree with Bill Mounce in https://www.billmounce.com/monday-with-mounce/should-we-capitalize-divine-pronouns that adding capitalizations for pronouns and Divine Titles is not something worth arguing about.

Second, I am no defender of any particular translation - I have not been involved in any capacity with any modern version.

It is true that some versions capitalize "Light" because they believe it is referring to Jesus, the Messiah in John 1:5-9 (not necessarily v4).  This section of John prologue anticipates John 8:12 where Jesus personally says:

> Once again, Jesus spoke to the people and said, “**I am the light of the
> world**. Whoever follows Me will never walk in the darkness, but will
> have the light of life.” (See also John 9:5, 1 John 1:5-7)

This appears to be an allusion to some references in the OT:

- Ps 27:1 - **The LORD is my light** and my salvation— whom shall I fear? The LORD is the stronghold of my life— of whom shall I be afraid?
- Micah 7:8 - Do not gloat over me, my enemy! Though I have fallen, I will rise. Though I sit in darkness, **the LORD will be my light**.

I assume (without actually knowing) that it is for this reason, that some versions capitalize "Light" is a few places that clearly refers to Jesus, such as BSB, BLB, NASB, NKJV, and a few more.

[I pause to note there is a similar practice in some versions with "Word" in places like John 1:1-3, 14, Rev 19:13.  But that is another question.]